# ClassNotFoundException coming for AppBarLayout, CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, material-design

When implementing Material Design and using AppBarLayout in the XML, ClassNotFoundException is coming for AppBarLayout, CoordinatorLayout etc. in the runtime of the app. Code compiles fine.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sivag1.juiceboard-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sivag1.juiceboard-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:255) 
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include the Android design library which is required for AppBarLayout and CoordinatorLayout.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add

```
compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.3.1"
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
```